# Pop out view model into separate window (like a Chrome tab)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel, visual-tree

My application consists of a single window with various view models displaying graphs/charts/tables, etc.  My users have decided they want the ability to pop out a chart and have it display in its own window, similar to how you can drag a tab out of Chrome, or a docked view out of Visual Studio, to see it in its own window.

I would like to avoid generating a new instance of the view model for use in the new window.

Is there a way to preserve the view model while moving it from one window to another?  And is there a way to easily remove the corresponding view from one visual tree and add it to another?

UPDATE:

I looked into AvalonDock and it's not quite what I'm looking for.  I just want to move an existing viewmodel from one part of the UI to a window.  Any ideas?

Comment: Use `AvalonDock` for Dock and undock like VS.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to avoid generating a new instance of the view model for
>   use in the new window.

I wonder why is that so? Anyways, you can achieve it this way:

```
// App.xaml.cs
public static MainViewModel MainVM {
    get {
        // create and return main view model once
    }
}

// Classes
public class MainViewModel {

    private ViewModel1 vm1;
    public ViewModel1 VM1 {
        get {
            return vm1;
        }
    }

    public void InitializeViewModel1() {
        ...
    }
}

public class ViewModel1 {
    ...
}
```

Although this will work in your case, I suggest you read about having static or single instance of viewmodels and decide if that's the approach you still want to follow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't answer the question.  I'm already doing this.  The problem is that WPF doesn't like to have a view model in the visual tree multiple times.  It doesn't quite generate all the view components properly.  I've seen some pretty weird stuff in my 3+ years with WPF.

Comment: I don't want to generate a new instance of the view model because then I'd have to save all of the user's changes out, so I could regenerate it in the exact state it was already in.  In VS they don't kill your VM before regenerating it in the new window.  They just move it.